# Using Tkinter to update checkbox results

Tags: python, csv, checkbox, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI where checkboxes are created based on a CSV file, so each option has a certain value attached to it. I need a way of making it such that when an option is selected, the value of that box is appended to a list, which can be summed and used in further calculation.

This is the Checkbox generation:

```
for row in data:
    if row[2] == "g":
        v=IntVar()
        Tkinter.Checkbutton(top,text=row[0],height=1,variable=v).grid(row=(row[3]),column=row[4],sticky=W)
        if v.get():
            tags.append(row[1])
```

Where "tags" is the list to be filled, with values from row[1]. row[3] and row[4] are just column/row settings.

I hope I've made it clear what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for any options :)

Comment: Do you have a specific programming question?

Comment: I want to know why the method I used isn't working, i.e. appending the associated value to "tags" if the checkbox has been filled. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not working for two reasons:

1) the value of variable `v` is only going to be attached to the last Checkbutton that's created. `v` is only one variable, no matter how many times it's created, and it takes the value of the last time it's created only.

2) because this line:

```
if v.get():
    tags.append(row[1])
```

is only going to be evaluated when the Checkbutton is created, not when it's clicked.

To fix this, you have several options. One of these options is assigning a `command` to a Checkbutton click, which passes the arguments `v` and `row[1]` to a callback function, which then adds the value of `row[1]` to your list.

Here's an example, you may have to adapt it to work for your code:

```
def callback(v,rowValue):
    if v.get():
        tags.append(rowValue)

for row in data:
    if row[2] == "g":
        v=IntVar()
        rowValue = row[1]
        c=Checkbutton(root,
                      text=row[0],
                      height=1,
                      variable=v,
                      command=lambda v=v, rowValue=rowValue: callback(v, rowValue))
        c.grid(row=(row[3]),column=row[4],sticky=W)
```